# Referencing the cell with the formula in it VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am trying to build a function to be used as a fixed reference point in a worksheet to be able to pull down formulas without the value in the created function changing the range of Hcom():
1, 1, 1, !Hcom into 
2, 2, 2, !Hcom
And so on

This if for use in a second function that is not fixed, I have tried to Dim rng as Range, I have tried to write ThisCell instead of Thiscell but vba auto-corrects to Thiscell. Googled a bit. i Have tried to write a If with = 1 Or 2 Or 3. I have tried Case select.

```
Function Hcom()
Dim rng as Range
Application.Volatile
Set rng = Application.Thiscell.Offset(0, 1)
Select Case rng
Case "SJUK", "VAB", "SEM.", "LEDIG", "RÖD D."
Hcom = Range("J7") / 5
Case Else
Hcom = ""
End Select
End Function
```

I want it to reference itself with Offset(0,1) to have it read a list of values. After finding the value i want or don't want it should wait for cells to change on the sheet? (First time using Application.Volatile) Instead i get #Value
As well as this error when i run it from VBA

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Method 'ThisCell' of object'_Application' failed

After debug this line gets highlighted

```
rng = Application.Thiscell.Offset(0, 1)
```

Comment: You need to pass a variable into your function.

Comment: Well you can't use `Application.ThisCell` if you're running from within VBA and not as a UDF. What is the value of `Range("J7")`?

Comment: To fix capitalization of `Thiscell` - add a new line `Dim ThisCell`, and then immediately delete it.

Comment: @urdearboy Thanks! Fixed it but i still need to enter a cell, Is there anyway to reference the cell the formula is in without entering anything outside vba?

Comment: What is the value of `Range("J7")`? `Hcom` should probably test if it is a number before attempting to divide by 5.

Comment: @bigben Range("J7") Is the value of a work week (20, 32, 40) for me depending the hours i have at the time. If i want to run it as UDF, do i do it in the sheet?

Comment: Yes. If you want to debug from VBA, change `Application.ThisCell.Offset(0, 1)` to the range in question. Then report back on the error that `Hcom = Range("J7") / 5` presumably throws.

Comment: @Bigben Okey! I changed Application.ThisCell.Offset(0, 1) to Range("H18") and went to debug -> Compile vba project But nothing happened.

Comment: You have to run it: add a new `Sub` and call `Hcom`. Step through with F8.

Comment: @Bigben called Hcom and got compile error, Argument not optional

Comment: That is because your latest version has a range argument. You would have to pass a range to it. But as I pointed out, your current code is functionally equivalent to your original one.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Function Hcom(YourOffset As Range, YourFixed As Range) As Variant
'Application.Volatile
Select Case YourOffset
    Case "SJUK", "VAB", "SEM.", "LEDIG", "RÖD D."
        Hcom = YourFixed / 5
    Case Else
        Hcom = ""
End Select
End Function
```

Comment: I tried this but i had to enter the cells on each row for the function to work and there are about 31-140 on each sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Hcom(ThisCell As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Application.Volatile
Set rng = Application.ThisCell.Offset(0, 1)
Select Case rng
Case "SJUK", "VAB", "SEM.", "LEDIG", "RÖD D."
Hcom = Range("J7") / 5
Case Else
Hcom = ""
End Select
End Function
```

Adding a Variable? to the First row fixed it by having a reference to itself and then offset.?
Not sure why it works :)

Comment: This actually fixed it? You never use `ThisCell`.

Comment: @Bigben i did this and now i enter Hcom(cell*) and it works. I can drag and fill as needed. For some reason :)

Cell = Cell with Hcom in it

Comment: The `ThisCell` that is an argument is not the same as `Application.ThisCell`. You never actually use the `ThisCell` that is passed as an argument. Your current code is equivalent to your original code. Try a different cell as the argument than the one with the formula in it - you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Bigben Okey! I tried it in a different cell and since the Values its looking for arent there it becomes 0. I am not sure what you want me to do. I still have to give the formula a range to work but it is better then adding a range to each row

Comment: What cell are you entering the formula in, and what is the exact formula you are entering?

Comment: If the `ThisCell` and `Application.ThisCell` were the same, then you'd have a circular reference. You don't actually have a circular reference, because you are not using the `ThisCell` that is an argument.